# Mongodb slave shut down

Tags: replication, mongodb

I started a mongodb master slave, but due to technical issues the slave server crashed. I restarted it and the mongod proccess as well with the host parameter, but for some reason the slave isn't replicating the data which was created when it was down. How can I tell the slave to get in sync with the master, including the existing data?

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using, and what error did you get when the node crashed? Are you actually using the older master/slave configuration or referring to a replica set secondary?

Comment: Im using the old master slave configuration, as all i need is 2 nodes and not 3. There was a problem with the server not the mongo, it had to be restarted

Comment: @user69153 you can use 1 primary, 1 secondary and 1 arbiter (e.g. on the same machine as primary) if you just need 2 data nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rs.slaveOk(1) on slave? On my side, slave even can't read data from collections after it come up again from down. So I make rs.slaveOk(1)  and Slave can read collections.